# How do I control the slider of the spotify playlist widget?

Tags: spotify

I am using the embed playlist widget mentioned here:
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/

I am able to use the play, pause, next, previous buttons. But I am unable to slide to a different position in the song. I need to go to the Web Player to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Seeking isn't supported by the Spotify Play Button, and I've updated the [Spotify Play Button documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/) to include that.